# Does the VB6 IDE highlight the wrong text when certain errors occur?

Tags: vb6, ide

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the VB6 IDE but I haven't found any definitive reference to it before...

Sometimes when I've loaded a project which has some dependency issue (missing reference, etc.) the IDE will show an error like this:

[image: h]

<sub>("*Compile error: Can't find project or library*")</sub>

Note the text which it highlighted **is a call to the `UCase$` function** **which is essentially built into the language.** There's no way its library is actually missing.

Is this a known bug? Is there any rhyme or reason to the text which is selected when this happens?

---

**Update:** The standard libraries which include things like `UCase()` *are* included so that is not the actual problem. The highlight really seems to be nonsensical.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that you have demanded of the compiler "Evaluate this!" by use of redundant parentheses.  But most likely the error comes from overloading the definition of UCase somewhere, screwing up the symbol table.

Comment: @bob77 not code I wrote myself :) ... Good thought on the symbol table I'll look into that. Thanks

Comment: Do a search on the entire Project for "UCase" and you may find that it got defined as something else somewhere.

Comment: How is sProjectName defined?

Comment: @Brogan it is just `Dim sProjectName        As String` in the same procedure.

Answer (score 0):

VB can do some strange things, but... check both the content and order of your References. `UCase$()` isn't 'built into the language' in the way you might think -- it's not in the VB runtime, but in the ***VBA*** runtime, which must be included as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, The VBA runtime is definitely OK so that's not the actual problem in this instance.